# it is possible to create lazyadapter For dynamic text and image in tablelayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-lazyadapter

i want to create adapter for table layout without using listview and use in table layout it is possible because when i find arrayadapter for tablelayout nothing is found all are work with listview but i have a table layout so any tutorial or stackoverflow question related to this than tell me it;s urgent